# Failed to parse TextMessage payload=[{"id" :1}], byteCount=9, last=true] in session Sending STOMP ERROR to client

Tags: java, spring-boot, websocket, stomp

I am using STOMP with spring java, I am able to connect to the application using simple in memory broker. But whenever I try to send any data to any of the destinations defined in my application I get the following error

```
 Failed to parse TextMessage payload=[{"id" :1}], byteCount=9, last=true] in session b1e46a4d-c608-af0b-1d1e-bd6bb896bae7. Sending STOMP ERROR to client.

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.StreamUtils.copyToString(Ljava/io/ByteArrayOutputStream;Ljava/nio/charset/Charset;)Ljava/lang/String;
```

Any idea if I missing any parser or necessary decoder required for STOMP to handle the incoming messages.[image: This is the image that show the error that the websocket client gets in reply to sending anything to the websocket server]

Answer (score 0):

I was eventually able to solve this issue. I was missing 2 major packages that STOMP required for proper decoding of the message:

```
compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-core', version: '2.10.2'
compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: '2.10.2'
```

So my final gradle build( which included all dependencies for message broker i.e. RabbitMQ
and also Web Socket Security ) with all the necessary dependencies required fore Websocket with STOMP on Spring 2.2.6.RELEASE looked like as below

```
compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-messaging', version: '5.2.2.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-websocket', version: '5.2.2.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-amqp', version: '2.3.1.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-messaging', version: '5.3.3.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-reactor-netty', version: '2.3.1.RELEASE'
compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-core', version: '2.10.2'
compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: '2.10.2'
compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-reactor-netty', version: '2.3.1.RELEASE'
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that this method `StreamUtils::copyToString(ByteArrayOutputStream baos, Charset charset)` has been added to Spring quite recently (since v.5.2.6 released on Apr 28, 2020) according to [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/StreamUtils.html#copyToString-java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream-java.nio.charset.Charset-).

So you need to check the dependencies in your project and make sure that `spring-integration-stomp` uses appropriate release of Spring.